Guideline for Deploying Multi-Feature Apps on App Store and Google Play
Will the App Store and Google Play allow the deployment of an app that integrates multiple features, such as money remittance, utilities bill payments, online dating, car rental, and real estate services etc ? Are there specific guidelines or restrictions I should be aware of when merging these functionalities into a single application?
I’m looking for specific guidelines but can’t find any
